# Uploading local photos to blog

Tags: files, media

I notice here that I can upload a photo from my computer, like this one:

[image: upload image from computer]

On my drupal site, I can do so as well, as an admininstrator. But for a regular authenticated user, I can't. Here's what regular users gets when they click on the upload media icon. Only access to gallery, not local files. Why?

[image: upload image from gallery]

Answer (score 1):

Go to permissions settings page `admin/people/permissions` and search for the permission '**Import media files from the local filesystem**'. Give this permission to all user roles that should be able to upload files from their local computer.